# Is there a way to create a windows phone 8 app in windows 7 and visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-8, windows-7

Is there a way to create and test an app (emulator for windows phone 8) in visual studio 2012 and windows 7? I got all the proper SDKs etc from Dreamspark but I cannot seem to find a way to do it in windows 7.  It's only "doable" in windows 8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

probably not, Microsoft only released it for Windows 8, but you can always have a virtual machine and Dreamspark also has licenses for Windows, so you won't have any issues with that neither.

Comment: side comment, I'm doing exactly the same, my machine is windows 7, and I have my virtual machine with licenses from dreamspark

Comment: my laptop heats up pretty fast in virtual machines and I am trying to avoid a format :D

Comment: yeah, actually the SDK demands a lot from the machine, so without the right equipment, you're out luck :-/

Comment: I'd also like to mention that the virtual machine route will be a no go too. Unless, perhaps, if you're deploying to a WP8 device. I've tried in both Virtualbox and VMWare Workstation and in both cases the emulator says it can't be loaded inside of another one or some such.

Comment: You need a fool blown Win8 Enterprise 64bit machine for the emulator to run

Answer (score 2):

No. Running the WP8 emulator on Win7 won't work. The WP8 emulator is based on Hyper-V which isn't supported on Win7. You can still develop WP8 apps on WIn7 and deploy to a real device. Or you should upgrade your Win7 installation to Win8 using your fre dreamspark license and then you could use the WP8 emulator.

Comment: how can I develop for windows 8? all I find is for windows phone 7.1

Comment: @Justin I think you cannot use the WP8 SDK at all in windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

No, the WP8 SDK will only run on Windows 8.A reason is the hypervisor in Windows 8 is used to emulate or virtualise Windows phone 8 machines. That and marketing of course.